# loop through multiple lists while creating workbooks in R

Tags: r

I recently got an R script from this site to create Excel workbooks in R. It has been working great for me except that now I want to loop this script through different "in" and "out" files but I am not sure how to do that. I know that I probably have to create lists like

```
f.in = c("Stata/Results/1st stage p/vrs/",
  "Stata/Results/1st stage p/crs/",
  "Stata/Results/1st stage np/vrs/",
  "Stata/Results/1st stage np/crs/")
```

and

```
f.out = c("Stata/Results/1st stage p/summaryVRS.xlsx",
  "Stata/Results/1st stage p/summaryCRS.xlsx",
  "Stata/Results/1st stage np/summaryVRS.xlsx",
  "Stata/Results/1st stage np/summaryCRS.xlsx")
```

But anyway, the following script is what I have currently. I have been running the script by commenting out different lines of `.in` and `.out` files, but that is very inefficient!

```
require(data.table)
require(XLConnect)

rm(list = ls())

setwd("S:/X productivity")

#folder/where/CSV_files_are_located

#folder = "Stata/Results/1st stage p/vrs/"
#folder = "Stata/Results/1st stage p/crs/"
#folder = "Stata/Results/1st stage np/vrs/"
folder = "Stata/Results/1st stage np/crs/"

#path/to/file.xlsx

#f.out <-  "Stata/Results/1st stage p/summaryVRS.xlsx"
#f.out <-  "Stata/Results/1st stage p/summaryCRS.xlsx"
#f.out <-  "Stata/Results/1st stage np/summaryVRS.xlsx"
f.out <-  "Stata/Results/1st stage np/summaryCRS.xlsx"

## load in file
wb <- loadWorkbook(f.out, create=TRUE)

## get all files
pattern.ext <- "\\.csv$"
files <- dir(folder, full=TRUE, pattern=pattern.ext)

## Grab the base file names, you can use them as the sheet names
files.nms <- basename(files)
files.nms <- gsub(pattern.ext, "", files.nms) #get rid of the .csv extention

i <-0
for (nm in files) {
  ## ingest the CSV file
  temp_DT <- fread(nm)

  ## Create the sheet where the file will be outputed to 
  i <-i+1
  fn <-files.nms[i]
  createSheet(wb, name=fn)

  ## output the csv contents
  writeWorksheet(object=wb, data=temp_DT, sheet=i, header=TRUE, rownames=NULL)
}

saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: Since you don't have any hits in an hour, you ought to now search for other SO questions with: `[r] loop over list files directory`. I think you will find quite a few worked examples. If you don't find any perfect fits, but one almost solves it any you have a residual question then edit you question. (Otherwise I predict it will get closed as a yet-another-HOWTO-loop-over-files question.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Honestly I am quite surprised I thought this would be an easy fix for any experienced R users...do you know if I can send my question to a couple specific users who answered my questions before and who i think should be able to solve it?

Comment: I briefly looked at your profile and it seems that you are also an experienced R user. Can you let me know why my question turns out to be such a tough cookie? I think it's the fact that i have two, instead of one, lists that need to be looped through simultaneously makes this question tricky...

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "tough cookie", in fact it's probably pretty easy to debug. It's almost certainly one that is not reproducible, since you are accessing material that only available on your device. It's also very likely to have been asked and answered in some form in the past and there was no evidence that you had made any attempt at searching for an answer before posting. I cannot really tell what the problem might be when you made an effort,since you have not posted any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I spent some more time thinking about this question and after many trials and errors I finally found a solution! I am sharing my codes here. When I was searching for answers, I found many experienced R users commented that one strength of R is its capability of avoid using looping. So if any of you can think of other clever ways to loop through 2 lists, I would love to learn them.

```
require(data.table)  ## for fast fread() function
require(XLConnect)

rm(list = ls())

setwd("S:/Controller productivity")

infolder = c("Matlab/Results/3rd stage p/vrs/original/",
         "Matlab/Results/3rd stage p/crs/original/",
         "Matlab/Results/3rd stage np/vrs/original/",
         "Matlab/Results/3rd stage np/crs/original/")

outfile =c("Stata/Results/1st stage p/summaryVRS.xlsx",
       "Stata/Results/1st stage p/summaryCRS.xlsx",
       "Stata/Results/1st stage np/summaryVRS.xlsx",
       "Stata/Results/1st stage np/summaryCRS.xlsx")

j <-0
for (inname in infolder) {

  j<-j+1

#folder/where/CSV_files_are_located
folder = inname

#path/to/file.xlsx
f.out <- outfile[j]

## load in file
wb <- loadWorkbook(f.out, create=TRUE)

## get all files
pattern.ext <- "\\.csv$"
files <- dir(folder, full=TRUE, pattern=pattern.ext)

## Grab the base file names, you can use them as the sheet names
files.nms <- basename(files)
files.nms <- gsub(pattern.ext, "", files.nms) #get rid of the .csv extention

i <-0
for (anything in files) {
  ## ingest the CSV file
  temp_DT <- fread(anything)

  ## Create the sheet where the file will be outputed to 
  i <-i+1
  fn <-files.nms[i]
  createSheet(wb, name=fn)

  ## output the csv contents
  writeWorksheet(object=wb, data=temp_DT, sheet=i, header=TRUE, rownames=NULL)
}

saveWorkbook(wb)

}
```